# Ajax Calendar extender conversion

Tags: c#

I have to AJAX calendar extender

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="txtFrom_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtFrom">
    </ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

I use this code to convert string in to datetime

```
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFrom.Text))
             Dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrom.Text.ToString().Trim());
         else
             Dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTo.Text))
             Dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTo.Text.ToString().Trim());
         else
             Dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
```

**I want to dd/MM/yyyy format but result is 09/03/2014 00:00:00**

Comment: Hey OP, none of these answer didn't solve your problem? Give some feedback at least..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`"d"` Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) if your culture uses `/` as a [`DateSeperator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It uses [`DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your current thread culture.

As an example;

```
Dt2.ToString("d");
```

Or you can use [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `DateTime.ToString()` method like;

```
Dt2.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.IvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFrom.Text))
             Dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrom.Text.ToString().Trim()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
         else
             Dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTo.Text))
             Dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTo.Text.ToString().Trim()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
         else
             Dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

**[Date Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**